# How to check Datatable column names?

Tags: c#

I have this error message: 
Cannot find column `[Nom complet]`.

My `datagridview` is `binded` by an Access data base where I have different tables.
From `Sauvegarde` table I have choose some column, and want to make a search filtration using a `combobox` in `[Nom complet]` column, but I get this message:
Cannot find column `[Nom complet]`.
I don't know where is the problem.
This is the code :

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
public recherche()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void filldata()
{
    OleDbConnection ccn = new         
    OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source='C:\mysource.accdb'");
    string qur = "Select [N], [Code machine], [Type programme], [Nom 
complet], [Motif], [Remarque] From [Sauvegarde]";
    OleDbCommand ccmd = new OleDbCommand(qur, ccn);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(ccmd);
    da.Fill(table);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
private void recherche_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filldata();
} 
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataView dv = new DataView(table);

    if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()=="All")
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
   else
   {
       dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[Nom complet] LIKE '%{0}%'", 
comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is more clear. Your problem is caused by the fact that you never initialize the global variable *table* but instead you create a local one. Then when you try to filter the global one you never find the column

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
....
private void filldata()
{
    .....
    // This creates a local DataTable variable with the same name of the global one
    // You are hiding the global and using the local one
    // DataTable table = new DataTable();

    // here instead you use the global variable
    // So you are referencing the same variable in the SelectedIndexChanged handler
    table = new DataTable();
    ....
}
```